# Returning Explicit Open XML results sets from a Table Value Function

Tags: sql-server, xml, openxml, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to return rows in Open XML form from a table value function in SQL Server (2008).
I'm occasionally getting errors when I select the results with "for xml explicit" which suggest that the order of the results is not guaranteed to be the same as the order I insert into the output of the TVF.

So my first question is: is that the case?

If so, my next question is: is there any way around this? The best I have been able to come up with so far is to include an id column in the TVF output, then select only the other columns when I call it, and order by id. The problem here is that it means I have to specify all the columns every time, rather than just selecting *, which is really awkward in this case (especially since I have 42 of these TVFs - all with different columns).

Do TVFs and Explicit Open XML just not mix (which would be a real shame as they seem to be a great fit), or am I missing something that will help?

Comment: What would I order by? Also I have order bys on some of the individual element generating queries, which I want to preserve. I have found one compromise so far, which I'll add as an answer, but I'm still hoping for better

Comment: misunderstood your post - removed my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found one compromise. It's still a little awkward, but not as bad as having to specify all the columns.

You can mark columns in the open xml format as "hide":

```
[Tagname!Tagnumber!!hide]
```

If I add an identity column to my output with a name following that form I can order by it in my external select, but it won't partake in the xml output if I use for "xml explicit".

I'd still rather the order "just worked", but if that's not possible I thought I should share this finding for anyone interested.